# importing firebase/auth in a file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

i saw this code
`import 'firebase/auth'` while working on firebase.
how does it work. What function/object are we importing? I thought importing worked as `import A from B`

Comment: If you are looking for way to initialize Firebase and using in React app, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68136646/proper-helper-or-custom-react-hook-to-add-and-initialise-firebase/68139373#68139373) might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true that you're not importing a function, class or variable from the auth-module. But modules can execute side effects. Imagine the following module:

```
console.log("I was imported");

export {};
```

By using an import like `import 'firebase/auth'` this code would be executed and the log would appear.

In case of firebase it think the import will add the `firebase.Auth` property to the global `firebase` object.